# How to access fields from auxiliary constructors in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala and learning it step by step. It may be a very vague and trivial question for others, but I want to learn from the experts.

My question is how to access the fields from the auxiliary constructors as we do in Java.

To make it clear, let me provide a simple example in Java.

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public Person() {
    // No arg constructor
  }

  public Person(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this(firstName);
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The test class is given below.

```
public class TestPerson {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("Sambit");
    System.out.println("First Name: " + p.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + p.getLastName());//<--- last name may be null
  }
}
```

As you can see that based upon the requirements, I can add new constructors and fields with getter setter methods to access. How can I do it in Scala, I do not use case class here.

My scala equivalent class is given below.

```
class Person {

  def this(firstName: String) {
    this();
  }

  def this(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    this(firstName);
  }
}

object TestPerson {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var p: Person = new Person("Sambit", "Mishra");
    println("Person: " + p)
    println("Person Last Name: " + p); <--- Here I can not access last name,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you're creating a class with two constructors, but without any fields. So equivalent in Java would be creating a class with constructors with parameters and then not assign these parameters to any fields.

You can create a class with 3 constructors following way:

```
//Here we declare that our class would have two fields.
//It also created primary constructor, which takes 2 arguments

class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {

  def this(firstName: String) { //second constructor
    this(firstName, "");
  }

  def this() { //third constructor
    this("");
  }
}
```

A side point is, that it is rarely needed in  Scala to create additional constructors because you can define default values for your fields:

```
class Person(val firstName: String = "", val lastName: String = "")

new Person()
new Person("fn")
new Person("fn","ln")
```

If you can't come up with usable default for your field, but you still want to make it optional, you can use `Option`:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: Option[String] = None)

new Person("fn")
new Person("fn",Some("ln"))
```

Comment: As an additional note, for representing optional fields, it would be better to use **Option** instead of an empty string.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for quick answer, from the above I understand that in case if I need to add another constructor, I need to add the required fields in the primary constructor and with optional default values like Python. Is my understanding correct Sir ?

Comment: @Sambit Yes, it's the usual way to handle required and optional fields. I also added an example with `Option` according to what Luis wrote.